# how to Give a selected TabBar a Gradient color?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I tried to subclass the UITabBar and applied a Gradient color but the code i used added the color to the whole tab bar section

Code Used:

```
class TabViewController : UITabBarController {
   
    let gradientlayer = CAGradientLayer()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    func setUpSelectionIndicatorImage(withColors colors: [UIColor]) {
        gradientlayer.frame = tabBar.bounds
        gradientlayer.colors = [colors[0].cgColor, colors[1].cgColor]
        gradientlayer.locations = [0, 1]
        gradientlayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
        gradientlayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        self.tabBar.layer.insertSublayer(gradientlayer, at: 0)
    }

     override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        let colors = [UIColor.IntroGradientColor1 , UIColor.IntroGradientColor2]
        setUpSelectionIndicatorImage(withColors: colors)
    }
    
}
```

Any idea how can i achieve this blue Gradient color ONLY on the selected tab like in the image attached .

[image: I want to achieve the gradient color in the tabbar that is selected]

Comment: Create two assets, selected and non-selected. Then set the image on the tab bar item to change when it becomes selected.

Comment: Well this looks really genius and cool hahah adn am gonna do it now. and am sure it will work but is there any other way !! to control the colors just so i know for later ?

Comment: Create a custom tabbar class, you cannot achieve this screen by change default tabbar controller.

Comment: @asilturk any idea or reference hot to do so. ?

Comment: @MahmoudZinji I was facing the kind of the same issue. Have you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

✅ This code helped me a lot to achieve this result!
[image]

Add these methods to the Delegate of your `UITabBarControllerDelegate`

```
func clearSelections(currentTabBar: UITabBar? = nil) {
    for view in currentTabBar?.subviews ?? self.tabBar.subviews {
        let gradient = view.layer.sublayers?.first(where: { layer in
            layer.name == "GradientLayerKey"
        })
        gradient?.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
}

func setSelection(item: UITabBarItem) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async(qos: .userInteractive) {
        for i in 0..<self.tabBar.items!.count {
            let ii = self.tabBar.items![i]
            if(item == ii) {
                let sv = self.tabBar.subviews[i+1]
                sv.clipsToBounds = true
                let one = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4352941176, green: 0.7960784314, blue: 0.9921568627, alpha: 1)
                let two = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3254901961, green: 0.4352941176, blue: 0.9254901961, alpha: 1)
                let gradientlayer = CAGradientLayer()
                gradientlayer.name = "GradientLayerKey"
                gradientlayer.frame = CGRect(
                    x: 0,
                    y: 8,
                    width: sv.layer.frame.width,
                    height: sv.layer.frame.height-8
                )
                gradientlayer.cornerRadius = 18
                gradientlayer.colors = [one.cgColor, two.cgColor]
                gradientlayer.locations = [0, 1]
                gradientlayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
                gradientlayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
                sv.layer.insertSublayer(gradientlayer, at: 0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage  bug fixed:

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()) {
        self.clearSelections(currentTabBar: tabBar)
    }
    if tabBar.selectedItem == item {
        setSelection(item: item)
    }
}
```